# Using javascript native import and async functions in the same file throws "Unexpected token" when compiling with Babel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, import, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to convert my angularJs directives to components by using the export function. 
I'm importing a service, injecting it into my component and exporting the component to be used.

If I comment out the async function and use a thenable, everything works fine.
Unfortunatly, browserify throws an "unexpected token" error on the line where the async function is declared.

```
import '../../services/my-service';

export default ['MyService', 
    function(MyService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: `<button ng-click="doAsyncFunction()"></button>`,
            scope: {

            },
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                angular.extend($scope, {
                    doAsyncFunction
                });

                async function doAsyncFunction() {
                    try {
                        return await 'Why wont this work?';
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
];
```

Comment: `return 'Why wont this work?';`

Comment: I used a string just for example, it's irrelevant if you await a string or a promise. That's not what causes the problem. The problem is the import statement that causes the async keyword as being an invalid token.

Comment: well, removing the string syntax error lets babel fully parse the code on https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: In the real code i'm calling a method on the service after the await function. Also, here, I'll change it to a string without spaces to not trigger a syntax error. Actually, the problem was un un-escaped " ' " character that was triggering the syntax error